# Conversion of 2D cvMat to 1D

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

How can I convert 2D `cvMat` to 1D? I have tried converting 2D `cvMat` to Numpy array then used `ravel()` (I want that kind of resultant matrix).When I tried converting it back to
 `cvMat` using `cv.fromarray()` it gives an error that the matrix must be 2D or 3D.

Comment: Couldn't you just convert the 1D array back to 2D before converting it to cvMat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `matrix.reshape((-1, 1))` to turn the *n*-element 1D matrix into an *n*-by-1 2D one before converting it.